# Unable to start Rails server nor console - (crack/xml) LoadError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, console

I've searched all around the web but haven't been able to find a resolution to this error. Each time I attempt to either start the rails server, or even rails console I get a `crack/xml (LoadError)`. Anyone have any suggestions that they believe might help me get rails up and running correctly?

```
Construct Coverage: rails s
/Users/Construct/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@coverage/gems/ap-0.1.1/lib/ap.rb:2:in `require': cannot load such file -- crack/xml (LoadError)
    from /Users/Construct/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@coverage/gems/ap-0.1.1/lib/ap.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/Construct/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require'
    from /Users/Construct/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from /Users/Construct/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `each'
    from /Users/Construct/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `block in require'
    from /Users/Construct/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
    from /Users/Construct/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Users/Construct/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler.rb:119:in `require'
    from /Users/Construct/Dropbox/rails_projects/Coverage/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/Construct/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@coverage/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `require'
    from /Users/Construct/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@coverage/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /Users/Construct/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@coverage/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
    from /Users/Construct/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@coverage/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

I've attempted to install the crack gem then run bundler but I'm still given the same error, even after a reboot of terminal. So I'm not exactly sure how to solve this scenario.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What is sure: the error stems from the ap gem, [this line](https://github.com/drcapulet/ap/blob/master/lib/ap.rb#L2).

It uses crack/xml as dependency but it's not stated as a dependency in the gemfile son bundler can't know it should be added.

How to fix?

- add the gem `crack` in your gemfile, before the `ap` gem
- or change the ap gem source code

Comment: Thanks sooooooo much for that. "add the gem crack in your gemfile, before the ap gem" totally fixed my issue. Although I did attempt to edit the ap gem source code and add crack as a dependency although it doesn't seem to have done any good.

Comment: It seems that the `ap` gem is outdated -- see the other answer that suggests the `awesome_print` gem.

Answer (score 7):

I got @apneadiving solution to work.

I also tried replacing

```
gem 'ap'
```

with

```
gem 'awesome_print'
```

in the Gemfile.

That appears to work too.

Update:
Seems that ap maybe the html/xml version of a awesome_print gem.